# AWS Mobile Hub User Pool

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-mobilehub

Where in the Mobile Hub after generating does the code reference the user pool? I have searched the project for my user pool name: testing_userpool_MOBILEHUB_xxxx but can't find it anywhere. Is it stored in a constants somewhere? I am new to Mobile Hub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention the language, but...

In iOS, there is an `Info.plist` file.  Look under `AWS/CognitoUserPool/Default` for the four keys that identify the user pool.

In Android, there is a file in `app/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobile` called `AWSConfiguration.java` that contains the definitions.

In JavaScript, you will adjust the `AWS.config` global variable.  This is generally set up in a file called `aws-config.js` within your project.

Comment: It was for an ios app.